# In a WPF application (with Devexpress), Store data for retrieval after the application is reopened

Tags: wpf, caching, mvvm, devexpress

I want to save the contents of a SelectedItem or Item's from a ComboBox as well as DataGrid Column Order so as retain the information when the application is reopened.
Initially I am using the below code for saving the data as long as the application is open:

```
App.Current.Properties[1] = SelectedDataSetList; 
App.Current.Properties[2] = SelectedModuleList;
App.Current.Properties[0] = SelectedContentSet;
```

SelectedDataSetList is bound to a ComboBox:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Text="SCOPE" x:Name="ContentSetCombobox" Grid.Column="1" Height="25" IncrementalFiltering="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ContentSetList}" DisplayMember="Name" AllowUpdateTwoWayBoundPropertiesOnSynchronization="False"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContentSet,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
```

But, I was unable to store the information in a Chache memory for retrieving even if the application is closed and opened again.

Is there any way to do this without using an external file like .xml?

Comment: Could you rephase _But, when I was unable to store the information in a Chache memory for retrieving even if the application is closed and opened again._? I cannot quite understand what is the problem here.

Comment: I was unable to store and retrieve information like Combobox.SelectedItem. I Tried using IsolatedStorage, but i do not know how to save a Dataset into an IsolatedStorage and get it back again.

Comment: U can also save the information in Registry

Comment: "without using an external file"? Not really. Take a look at [Using Application Settings and User Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings)

Comment: I think the problem is that the SelectedItem of the combobox is not simple data type like string or integer so it cannot directly be added to app settings. An external xml file to store the dataset is not a bad choice.

Comment: Any idea on how to save a Class or dataset into an IsolatedStorage and retrieve it back?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to save to IsolatedStorage you can use this class I've put together (see below). It's not perfect and will fail if you try to save a type that isn't marked as Serializable but it's good enough for casual use. I've left exception handling as an exercise for the OP.

```
public class IsolatedStorageManager
{
    public void Save<T>(T item, string key)
    {
        var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);
        using (var writeStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(key, FileMode.Create, isf))
        {
            Serialise(item, writeStream);
        }
    }

    public T Open<T>(string key)
    {
        var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);
        using (var readStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(key, FileMode.Open, isf))
        {
            var item = Deserialise<T>(readStream);
            return item;
        }
    }

    private Stream Serialise<T>(T item, Stream stream)
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, item);
        return stream;
    }

    private T Deserialise<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var item = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        return (T) item;
    }
}
```

Saving classes and datasets is demonstrated in the test fixture below.

```
[TestFixture]
public class IsolatedStorageManagerTestFixture
{
    private IsolatedStorageManager _underTest;
    private const string SaveFileKey = "TestSaveFileKey";

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _underTest = new IsolatedStorageManager();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestSavingDataset()
    {
        var tableName = "TestTable";

        var ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable(tableName));
        _underTest.Save(ds, SaveFileKey);

        var saved = _underTest.Open<DataSet>(SaveFileKey);

        Assert.That(saved.Tables.Count==1);
        Assert.That(saved.Tables[0].TableName == tableName);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestSavingClass()
    {
        var list = new ArrayList {"Hello", new DataTable(), 2};

        _underTest.Save(list,SaveFileKey);

        var saved = _underTest.Open<ArrayList>(SaveFileKey);

        Assert.That(saved.Count==3);
        Assert.That(string.Equals((string)saved[0], "Hello"));
        Assert.That(list[1] is DataTable);
        Assert.That((int)list[2] == 2);
    }
}
```